# Error on booting ubuntu After installation on HP laptop - System BootOrder not found LoadImage failed: Not Found

Tags: dual-boot, usb, windows-10, bios, boot-order

I can download and try ubuntu, but as soon as I do download it and run it, I get this error.

[1][image]

Text version:

```
System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults.

LoadImage failed: Not Found
Device Path: "PciRoot(0)/Pci(0x1F, 0x2)/Sata(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)/HD(Part2, Sig48FB7844-87C5-4CF2-B60C-87588C950D2F)/\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi"
02 01 0C 00 D0 41 03 0A 00 00 00 00 01 01 06 00
02 1F 03 12 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 01 2A 00
02 00 00 00 00 18 0E 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 03 00
00 00 00 00 44 78 FB 48 C5 87 F2 4C B6 0C 87 58
8C 95 0D 2F 02 02 04 04 34 00 5C 00 45 00 46 00
49 00 5C 00 75 00 62 00 75 00 6E 00 74 00 75 00
5C 00 73 00 68 00 69 00 6D 00 78 00 36 00 34 00
2E 00 65 00 66 00 69 00 00 00 7F FF 04 00
```

One last thing to mention is that I can't turn on "Secure Boot" in the BIOS.

Comment: "I can download and try ubuntu," -- Does that mean you created an install medium and booted that medium?  Your description doesn't match that.  There are detailed instructions available.  Which are you following?

Answer (score 0):

Turn off fastboot!! Windows10 that should work, or check your boot medium has ll the required files/folders, how did you weite the iso?